# I need to check the itunes store to see if a user has bought a subscription in the past version of my app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, subscription

I'm rolling out a new version of an iPad app, and you could buy subscriptions on the old version. However, the new app has different subscriptions than the old one did, but I still need to know if they used to have a subscription, so I can apply it to the new app.

So, how can I check the iTunes store to see if they bought a certain product in the past when they load the app? From what I can tell it should be possible to do because it is the same app and connected to the same app ID in the iTunes store.

I'm trying to get some sample code to put in here but I have literally no idea where to even start.

Comment: Recurring or non-recurring? Apple provides no mechanism for discovering old non-recurring subscriptions.

Comment: It's a lifetime subscription.. is there a way to see how much money they've spent on my app instead?

Comment: I just checked and it's just called "non-consumable".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SKPaymentQueue`'s `-restoreCompletedTransactions` to restore everything apart from non-recurring subscriptions. Your observer should get then receive every relevant transaction since the beginning of time, each with a state of `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`.

Apple requires you to support transaction restoration so hopefully your old version's code should have this built in somewhere, behind a 'restore' button or similar.

Comment: Is non-recurring the same as a non-renewing subscription? I don't see a non-recurring option when I just tried to make a new in-app purchase.

Comment: Yes, but it's a distinct thing from a non-consumable.